# How to restrain mouse cursor from leaving a QWidget area in PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a widget containing two buttons that can be (drag and drop) swapped using the mouse middle button. I am trying to restrain the mouse cursor from leaving the QWidget area when dragging and dropping a Qpushbutton... I am using dragMoveEvent() which offsets the cursor every time it crosses the border of the widget. It works when you move the mouse slowly but fast movements will make the cursor leave the area. What is the best way to make this happen? Thanks.

PS: Go to the Drag and Drop area for reference

```
import os
import random
import sys
import time
from PySide2 import QtOpenGL
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent, QMimeData, QPoint, QRect
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor, QDrag, QWindow
# import nuke
# import nukescripts
from collapse import Collapse
try:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
except ImportError:
    from PySide2 import QtCore
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets as QtGui
    from PySide2 import QtGui as QtG

class CreateNodeBoard(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.nukePathSeparator = "/"
        #self.toolPath = self.getFullPathWithExt()
        self.currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    ################################################################################
    # GUI
    ################################################################################
        self.setMinimumWidth(350)        
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.target = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.nodeBoardWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.nodeBoardWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        nodeBoardVLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.nodeBoardWidget.setLayout(nodeBoardVLayout)

        self.userButtonLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        nodeBoardVLayout.addLayout(self.userButtonLayout)
        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("a")
        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("b")
        self.userButtonLayout.addWidget(button1)
        self.userButtonLayout.addWidget(button2)
        self.userButtonLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nodeBoardWidget)
    def get_index(self, pos):
        for i in range(self.userButtonLayout.count()):
            buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(i).widget().mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)) 
            if QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(pos) and i != self.target:
                return i
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:           
            self.target = self.get_index(QCursor.pos())
        else:
            self.target = None
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):        
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton and self.target is not None:
            print("moving")
            drag = QDrag(self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget())
            pix = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget().grab()
            mimedata = QMimeData()
            mimedata.setImageData(pix)
            drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
            drag.setPixmap(pix)
            drag.setHotSpot(QPoint(40,10))
            drag.exec_()
            
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        cursorPos = QCursor.pos()
        widgetPos = self.nodeBoardWidget.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))
        if cursorPos.x() < widgetPos.x() or cursorPos.y() < widgetPos.y():
           QCursor.setPos(QCursor.pos().x() + 1 , QCursor.pos().y() + 1 )
        event.accept()
    

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("drag enter event")
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
              event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("drop")
        buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget().mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        if not QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(QCursor.pos()):
            source = self.get_index(QCursor.pos())
            if source is None:
                return

            i, j = max(self.target, source), min(self.target, source)
            p1, p2 = self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(i), self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(j)

            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(i), *p2)
            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(j), *p1)
            self.target = None

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a Qt widget, which will be our window.
window = CreateNodeBoard()
window.show()  # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

# Start the event loop.
app.exec_()
```

---

EDIT

---

So after further investigation and testing the code on both LINUX/WINDOWS I have come to the conclusion that both behaviours are caused by the programme exceeding the maximum recursion limit. Any time the mouse cursor during the drag event leaves the assigned widget something causes the events to call each other and this causes my app to crash. Having this as a standalone app does not cause any problem and I do not know why? Also, I have no ideas how this programme goes into recursion.

The previous solution of mine where I tried to create a "safe zone" for the mouse did not solve the issue as far as there are certain mouse movements causing the same bug.

Here is a better version of a working code. As I have already mentioned it works as a standalone GUI but causes the programme to crash within another software environment.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

try:
    from PySide import QtWidgets, QtCore
except ImportError:
    from PySide2 import QtCore
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets
    from PySide2 import QtGui
    from PySide2 import QtOpenGL


class CreateNodeBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    ################################################################################
    # GUI
    ################################################################################

        self.setMinimumWidth(350)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.target = None
        self.targetWidget = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    ################################################################################
    # GUI - NODE BOARD
    ################################################################################

        # Create a Layout to hold all widgets
        self.nodeBoardWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.nodeBoardWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        nodeBoardVLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.nodeBoardWidget.setLayout(nodeBoardVLayout)

        # create a grid layout inside nodeBoaardVLayout and load buttons from JSON
        self.userButtonLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        nodeBoardVLayout.addLayout(self.userButtonLayout)

        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('button1')
        self.userButtonLayout.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('button2')
        self.userButtonLayout.addWidget(button2)

        button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test button')
        button3.clicked.connect(self._test)
        self.userButtonLayout.addWidget(button3)

        self.userButtonLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nodeBoardWidget)
        nodeBoardVLayout.addStretch(1)

    ############################################################################
    # test
    ############################################################################

    def _test(self):
        print(self.topLevelWidget())

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print("dragLeaveEvent :", event)

        # XXX: does not work on macOS
        # self.drag.cancel()

        # parent = self.parent().mapToGlobal(self.drag.hotSpot())
        # QtGui.QCursor.setPos(parent.x() + 50, parent.y() + 50)

        # XXX: could still causes a crash
        # q = QMessageBox()
        # q.setText('no can do')
        # q.exec_()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        pass

    ################################################################################
    # DRAG AND DROP
    ################################################################################

    def get_index(self, pos):
        for i in range(self.userButtonLayout.count()):
            buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(
                i).widget().mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
            if QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(pos) and i != self.target:
                return i

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.target = self.get_index(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

        else:
            self.target = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if event.buttons() and QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton and self.target is not None:
            print("mouseClickEvent :", event)

            self.drag = QtGui.QDrag(
                self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget())
            pix = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget().grab()
            mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
            mimedata.setImageData(pix)
            self.drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
            self.drag.setPixmap(pix)
            self.drag.setHotSpot(QtCore.QPoint(40, 10))
            self.drag.exec_()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        # print("dragMoveEvent :", event)
        cursorPos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        widgetPos = self.nodeBoardWidget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
        if cursorPos.x() <= widgetPos.x() or cursorPos.y() <= widgetPos.y():
            QtGui.QCursor.setPos(QtGui.QCursor.pos().x() +
                                 10, QtGui.QCursor.pos().y() + 10)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("dragEnterEvent :", event)
        # XXX: if ignored, will not crash but will not propagate events
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # print("dropEvent :", event)
        buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(
            self.target).widget().mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        if not QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(QtGui.QCursor.pos()):
            source = self.get_index(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            if source is None:
                return

            i, j = max(self.target, source), min(self.target, source)
            p1, p2 = self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(
                i), self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(j)

            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(i), *p2)
            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(j), *p1)
            self.target = None


class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.test_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.set_test()

        _layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        _layout.addWidget(CreateNodeBoard())
        _layout.addWidget(self.test_widget)

        self.setLayout(_layout)

    def set_test(self):
        """Adjacent test widget"""
        self.test_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.test_widget.setPalette(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))

        _test_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        _test_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('TEST WIDGET'))

        self.test_widget.setLayout(_test_layout)


try:
    import nukescripts
except ImportError as error:
    APP = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    WINDOW = TestWidget()
    WINDOW.show()
    APP.exec_()
else:
    nukescripts.panels.registerWidgetAsPanel(
        'TestWidget', 'DragDrop',
        'DragDrop.MainWindow')
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. avoid confusing imports and mixed usage of modules; since you clearly are importing from PySide2 (the try/except block that comes afterward is useless) use the modules as they should. QtGui is an *important* module of Qt5, and trying to "overwrite" its name by using "QtG" for QtGui is not only unnecessary, but simply *wrong*. It's pretty clear you're "patching" your way by copying code from various sources, but doing it should always be done with awareness: so, use correct module names by learning what classes they provide. 2. avoid unnecessary and distracting imports in->

Comment: ->your examples, they are of no use, and can potentially lead people to just ignore your question because your code has too many imports that have to be commented out: people answering you should focus on providing the answer, not cleaning out your code (that's *your* job); 3. avoid unnecessary code and comments, and use more consistent spacing between classes and functions (2 lines and 1, respectively);

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the reply, the point of the code is to have a working example of what my app looks like. It is a partial code used in a totally different app and I am not asking anyone to fix my mistakes or anything similar. I am simply asking for an answer to the question in a context of the code provided.

Comment: I know that this is not your complete code, and that's exactly my point: when providing an example, you should ensure that it only contains code relevant for the question, without any other distraction. Examples should always be [not only reproducible, but also minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and possibly by following good styling conventions (spaces, namings, etc). People answering to you should focus on the issue by understanding what the code does, not being distracted by how the code is written. Consider that creating a *good* question ->

Comment: -> takes a lot of time, including the time required to craft a *well written* example. I created questions that took me way more than an hour in order to make them good. That's because good questions should go straight to the point, provide relevant details and avoiding anything unnecessary to the matter at hand, and the same concepts should also be used in the attached code. For instance, your imports alone take 17 lines that could have been just two instead (sys and PySide), and create confusion in your code ("replacing" QtGui and using it along with QtWidgets) not only to us, but to you too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will make sure that in future questions these principles will be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND A FIX:

the dragEnterEvent caused the whole thing to go into recursion which causes the app to crash. (Linux terminal kept showing maximum recursion limit exceeded every time I moved the dragEvent outside the widgets area)

So to fix this I have created a condition inside the dragEnterEvent that if the mouse cursor moves outside the widgets it should ignore the event.

```
    ################################################################################
    # DRAG AND DROP
    ################################################################################

    def get_index(self, pos):
        for i in range(self.userButtonLayout.count()):
            buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(i).widget().mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0,0)) 
            if QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(pos) and i != self.target:
                return i
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:           
            self.target = self.get_index(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton and self.target is not None:
                drag = QtGui.QDrag(self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget())
                pix = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget().grab()
                mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
                mimedata.setImageData(pix)
                drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
                drag.setPixmap(pix)
                drag.setHotSpot(QtCore.QPoint(40,10))
                drag.exec_()
        else:
            self.target = None

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        if self.cursorInWidget():
            drag = QtGui.QDrag(self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget())
            drag.cancel()

    def cursorInWidget(self):
        cursorPos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        widgetWidth = self.nodeBoardWidget.geometry().width()
        widgetHeight = self.nodeBoardWidget.geometry().height()        
        widgetPos = self.nodeBoardWidget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0,0))
        if cursorPos.x() <= widgetPos.x() or cursorPos.y() <= widgetPos.y() or cursorPos.x() >= (widgetPos.x() + widgetWidth) or cursorPos.y() >= (widgetPos.y() + widgetHeight):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if self.cursorInWidget():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        buttonGlob = self.userButtonLayout.itemAt(self.target).widget().mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        if not QtCore.QRect(buttonGlob.x(), buttonGlob.y(), 80, 23).contains(QtGui.QCursor.pos()):
            source = self.get_index(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            if source is None:
                return
            i, j = max(self.target, source), min(self.target, source)
            p1, p2 = self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(i), self.userButtonLayout.getItemPosition(j)

            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(i), *p2)
            self.userButtonLayout.addItem(self.userButtonLayout.takeAt(j), *p1)
            self.target = None
```

Answer (score 0):

### Premise

This answer is very limited to the specific question (prevent the user to move the mouse outside the boundaries of the given widget). Unfortunately, it's not a complete solution due to many conceptual problems in the given code:

1. both drag *and* drop events should always be managed by the widget that will actually handle them (in this case, `nodeBoardWidget`), not their parent;
2. getting the layout index of an item should **always** consider the item geometry (using a fixed size is discouraged, since widget sizes depend on lots of aspects) and the fact that an item could **not** be a widget (nested layouts are still layout items, so `layout.itemAt().widget()` could return `None`);
3. "swapping" items based on item indexes doesn't always keep the item index, as the resulting indexes could be unreliable (especially for grid layouts);

### Partial solution

The important aspect to keep in mind is that trying to move the mouse by a small and fixed amount to "fix" its position is wrong, because mouse events are not continuous: if the mouse is moved very fast from `x=0` to `x=100` you don't get all values between 0 and 100, but only a small fraction of the intermediate positions.
For the same reason, trying to "fix" the position just by a fixed amount of pixels is wrong, since the offset can be variable depending on the mouse speed.

The above results in `dragMoveEvent` not being called if the mouse moves too fast outside the parent boundaries. While in your specific case it "works", it's only because you implemented the function in the parent (which, as said, is not the suggested approach, and this is a clear example of that reason). If the mouse position has to be "contained", the `dragLeaveEvent` must be implemented instead.

```
class CreateNodeBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # ...
        self.targetWidget = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
            if (widget != self.nodeBoardWidget and 
                self.nodeBoardWidget.isAncestorOf(widget)):
                    self.targetWidget = widget

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.targetWidget:
            drag = QDrag(self.targetWidget)
            pix = self.targetWidget.grab()
            mimedata = QMimeData()
            mimedata.setImageData(pix)
            drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
            drag.setPixmap(pix)
            drag.setHotSpot(QPoint(40,10))
            drag.exec_()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if self.nodeBoardWidget.isAncestorOf(event.source()):
            event.accept()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        geo = self.nodeBoardWidget.rect().translated(
            self.nodeBoardWidget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint()))
        pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        if pos not in geo:
            if pos.x() < geo.x():
                pos.setX(geo.x())
            elif pos.x() > geo.right():
                pos.setX(geo.right())
            if pos.y() < geo.y():
                pos.setY(geo.y())
            elif pos.y() > geo.bottom():
                pos.setY(geo.bottom())
            QtGui.QCursor.setPos(pos)
```

<sup>I strongly suggest you to study the above example and considerations, as your code has lots of conceptual issues that my answer could not fix if not by creating a completely new example done from scratch. Also, since it's pretty clear that you're getting your code from various sources found on the web, I also suggest you to do that with *awareness*. Imitation is a good way of learning, but not without understanding what is being done. Do your research on **all** functions and classes used, and study all the related documentation, starting from [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), [drag and drop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) and not forgetting about [official code styling practices](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sup>

Comment: This code did not provide a solution, Dragging the button too fast causes it to leave the border of the widget just like in the sample code provided in the initial question.

Comment: @FilipSuska please ensure that you're **only** using the above functions, before trying to "merge" with your code. I tested it and it correctly works, so if it doesn't in your case it's because you didn't properly implement it.

Comment: first of all  in dragLeaveEvent() ---> line "if pos not in geo:" this creates a TypeError: argument of type 'PySide2.QtCore.QRect' is not iterable. So I had to change to code to "if not geo.contains(pos):". Then I just created two buttons inside the nodeBoardWidget and the results are still the same..... the cursor leaves the widget border

Comment: @FilipSuska that's because PySide2 didn't implement the `__contains__` operator as PyQt does, but besides that it should work (I tested with PySide2 to be sure). Are you by any chance using a virtual machine? If that's so, you must disable mouse integration in order to make it working as expected.

Comment: I am using Windows OS, and the behaviour of your example does exactly the same when you get close to the border of the widget it pushes the cursor away from it but after fast movement, it leaves the widget boundaries, however, it show the "you cannot drop here" icon.